# Reflectivity of a glass+film

Tags: optics

> A Ti02 film of index 2.5 is placed on glass of index 1.5 to increase
> the reflection in the visible. Choosing a suitable value for wavelength, how
> thick a layer in microns would you want, and what reflectivity would this
> give you?

My question is about the last question presented above. Precisely, i am having some trouble to understand what it means by "reflectivity", i guessed that it is the coefficiente R that points the intensity obtained from a reflection, in this case normal, so generally $r_{12}=(\frac{n_1 - n_2}{n_1 + n_2})^2$. In this case, i thought that, since we want to increase the reflection and at the same time decrease the intensity, the reflected wave need to be out of phase by pi and the reflectivity would be $|r_{10}-r_{12}|$, where 0 is the air, one is the film and two is the glass.

But, the answer is $r=(\frac{n_0 - n_1²/n_2}{n_0 + n_1²/n_2})^2$, i have no idea how does the author got this answer. Any help?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Fresnel reflection coefficient for thin-film interference? You want to optimize reflection, so the phase factor is 1, and then you plug in the single-interface reflection coefficients for transmission into and out of the thin film as well as the reflections within.